# Save filter for a HTTP Post API call in .NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, html, .net-core

Currently i am developing a web-application in .net core mvc 3. The filter is shown in the image below. If i use the filter for the max amount of results - i switch the toggle from 25 to 50 for example.

[image]

If the user is leaving the current view, because he needs some detail informations or something else and comes back to this site with the shown filter - the filter is set to the default values.

How could i do a "saved" filter for a session? Currently my code looks like the following example. I am using therefor an AJAX HTTP POST "call".

Thanks for your help.

```html
<form id="filterForm" asp-controller="Reference" asp-action="Mappings" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="#updateContainer">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Start</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Verknüpfungen</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- MY PARTIAL WITH FILTER LIKE THE IMAGE AND THE FILTER MODEL IS HERE -->
            @Html.Partial("_MappingsFilter", new ModulareArbeitsanweisung.Models.Reference.MappingsFilter(requestType))
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" id="updateContainer">
            <!-- MY CONTENT WHICH IS FILTERED IS HERE -->

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your option is either cookie or server side session.

Comment: How could a implementation look like?

Comment: Too lazy to create one, but session arguably would be simplest, here is some reading where you can save and retrieve session values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-and-get-session-values